# xprintf doesn't use stdout. How does it still print on screen?

Tags: c++, c, printf, stdout

For a `C++` project at work I use the `GLPK` (Gnu Linear Programming Kit written in `C`). When I use some procedures in a console application there is an automatic output generated from `GLPK`.

Now after I packed all that in a GUI I wanted to use the formerly diplayed text. So I redirected the stdout and stderr to files. (And I checked it works fine with `printf("Hallo World");` in my app).

The problem is that the text form the `GLPK` doesn't appear in the files. After some research I saw that the statement `xprintf(...)` was used. (Honestly I don't have a clue what `xprintf` does and what the difference to `printf` is.)

Can someone please explain:

1. How the text is printed on the screen without stdout.
2. How do I get the automatic generated output to a file or a stream or whatever I can handle.

Comment: Have you checked whether it uses `stderr`?

Comment: Perhaps its so simple. I thought I have redirected stderr to error.txt. But my test to print an error didn't show up in the error.txt. I have to double check it.

Comment: stderr is redirected to error.txt. (checked with `fprintf( stderr, "ERROR1");` strangly `perror("ERROR2");` doesn't appear in error.txt (I have to say thats the first time I used that statement and i am not familiar with its behaviour)

Comment: @MartinHoratschek The standard `perror` function always prints to stderr, so if you're not seeing its output in your error file after the process has finished, either you (or GLPK) are not using the standard `perror` function, or you're not redirecting stderr properly (which your comment says you've tested).

Comment: Which version of GLPK are you using ? How do you redirect `stdout` to a file ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker GLPK 4.47 and `freopen_s(&streamout, "out.txt", "w", stdout);` in VS2010

Comment: then it has most likely to do with the way you build and/or run the application. I am no expert on VS though, so I can't help with that. But rephrasing the question to be about VS2010, `freopen_s` and a dll that writes to `stdout` would likely get you a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xprintf` (alias for `glp_printf`) used internally by GLPK writes to `stdout` in the normal case (for the latest GLPK version 4.47).

There are a few ways to change the behavior of `glp_printf` :

- disable output using `glp_term_out(GLP_OFF)`
- install a hook using the `glp_term_hook` function which can redirect the output anywhere the hook wants
- write a copy of the output to a text file - this can be set up using the `glp_open_tee` function

If you haven't used any of the above, and still can't redirect the `stdout` output, then there might be something wrong with how you're redirecting the output.

Comment: I acceptet that as my answer because it offered a solution to my main problem. I just used `glp_open_tee("tee.tee");` and got all I wanted. The redirection of stdout was just my try to do what that statement does. I thank all of you who offered your help.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How text is printed on the screen without stdout.

Your average `stdout` is an output stream that *happens* to be connected to the terminal by default. You can do anything with it that could be done with a stream, including `reopen()` it to a file.

And just as you can use `fopen()` to create another stream writing to a file, you can also use it to create another stream writing to the terminal (which would be `/dev/tty` in Linux). Output written to that stream would appear on your terminal, despite not going through stdout.

stdout is merely a handy default, by no means the only way to access the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

stdout by default is buffered so text will be refreshed only after every new line.
It is possible that one of your libraries or even xprintf itself alters behaviour of stdout.
Basically you are not guaranteed to see previous printf() output if that output does not end with a newline.

Try to use:

```
fflush (stdout);
```

after xprintf.

fflush is in stdio.h

Usually xprintf is non-mallocing printf.

Comment: I wonder what "commonly" means in this context. `xprintf()` is not a standard function, and I couldn't find any documentation on it *ad hoc*.

Comment: I edited to usually. One of implementation on non-mallocing printf is: [xprintf](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/xprintf).

Comment: I wrote my own non-malloc'ing `printf()`, thank you. ;-) I felt that needlessly calling `malloc()` from a standard function is somewhat braindead - and it *is* needless in the context of printf(). ;-)

Comment: Just curious - why would `printf()` need dynamic memory?  And does glibc (or another common C runtime library) do such a thing?

Comment: In stdio-common/vfprintf.c there are lot of calls to malloc and printf() seems to resolve to using vfprintf. 
Dynamic memory was probably implemented there to create expendable buffer for changing character representation and such.

Answer (score 0):

In GLPK, `xprintf` is a macro alias for `_glp_lib_xprintf` (defined in `glplib.h`).

`xprintf()` is implemented in `glplib04.c`.  By default it does output to `stdout` (via an `xputc()` function in the same source file).  There are various configuration options that can change the behavior of `xputc()`.

You might want to set a breakpoint on `_glp_lib_xprintf()` and step through to see what's going on.

Comment: I would love to try it. But I linked the `glpk_4_47.dll` and i dont see a way to set a breakpoint there.

Comment: I think you should just have to build a debug version of the DLL with symbols.